# How to inner function variable can access outer function variable using closure in javascript

Tags: javascript

Inner function variable can access outer function variable, it is possible or not in java script.I am confusing for the closures.

```
function a(){
var x=10;
console.log(x,y);
return function b(){
var y=20;
console.log(x,y);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inner function variables can access outer function variables, BUT NOT THE OTHER WAY AROUND. Very good clarifying question.  Below is a simple example of a function accessing a variable in an encompassing scope.

```js
var name = 'John';
var Person = function(){
  this.name = name;
}
var guy = new Person();
guy.name //John
```

```js
function a(){
  var x=10;
  console.log(x);
  return function b(){
    var y=20;
    console.log(x,y);
  }
}
var x = a();
console.log('x defined')
x();
```

Try running this to see the sequence of interpretation in javascript

Comment: For the above Example i have print 10 & 20 but 10 is printed and Y is not defined,why?

Comment: javascript will run the line console.log(x,y) before y is defined, so y will be logged as undefined.

if you run the returned function, y will be defined at that point, and the second console.log will log properly